# Table does not overflow inside a flexbox in firefox and MS Edge

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox

I have a page with a flexbox div and inside the second flex div I have a table, if I resize it all the elements accommodate to the windows and the table has a horizontal scroll to move around it. All of this work in chrome and IE but in firefox and MS Edge the table breaks the width of the window and does not have horizontal scroll.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/chuvask/175bevzo/

HTLM

```
<div id="flexContainer">
<div style="flex-basis: 27%;" id="objetivosContainer" class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Objetivos</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div>
            <form novalidate="novalidate" id="frmAddObjetivo"><div class="form-group actions"><input id="txtObjetivo" name="txtObjetivo" class="form-control txtInput" placeholder="Nombre del objetivo" type="text"><a id="agregarObjetivo" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></div></form>
        </div>
        <div id="objetivosList"><div class="list-group"><li style="background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);" class="list-group-item objetivoItemContainer"><div class="objetivoItem" onclick="iniciativasEstrategicas.GetObjetivosInfo(this)"><span>Garantizar sostenibilidad financiera</span></div><div class="objetivoItemButtons"><a id="editObjetivo" onclick="iniciativasEstrategicas.EditObjetivo(this);"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a><a id="deleteObjetivo" onclick="iniciativasEstrategicas.DeleteObjetivo(this);"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></div><span class="hdnIdObjetivo" style="display:none">1</span></li><li style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" class="list-group-item objetivoItemContainer"><div class="objetivoItem" onclick="iniciativasEstrategicas.GetObjetivosInfo(this)"><span>Garantizar el servicio óptimo a nuestros clientes</span></div><div class="objetivoItemButtons"><a id="editObjetivo" onclick="iniciativasEstrategicas.EditObjetivo(this);"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a><a id="deleteObjetivo" onclick="iniciativasEstrategicas.DeleteObjetivo(this);"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></div><span class="hdnIdObjetivo" style="display:none">2</span></li><li style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" class="list-group-item objetivoItemContainer"><div class="objetivoItem" onclick="iniciativasEstrategicas.GetObjetivosInfo(this)"><span>Garantizar crecimiento de nuestros clientes</span></div><div class="objetivoItemButtons"><a id="editObjetivo" onclick="iniciativasEstrategicas.EditObjetivo(this);"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a><a id="deleteObjetivo" onclick="iniciativasEstrategicas.DeleteObjetivo(this);"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></div><span class="hdnIdObjetivo" style="display:none">3</span></li></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="display: block;" id="divPestanasObjetivos">
    <ul id="pestanasObjetivos" class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a id="dashboard" href="#tab_dashboard" data-toggle="tab" onclick="iniciativasEstrategicas.GetObjetivosInfo('cache')">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a id="iniciativas" href="#tab_iniciativas" data-toggle="tab" onclick="iniciativasEstrategicas.GetIniciativas()">Iniciativas</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div style="" id="pestanasObjetivosContent" class="tab-content">
        <div style="" class="tab-pane dashboard fade in active" id="tab_dashboard">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class=""><a aria-expanded="false" id="iniciativasPorcentaje" href="#tab_iniciativasPorcentaje" data-toggle="tab" onclick="iniciativasEstrategicas.GetIniciativasPorcentaje()">Iniciativas</a></li>
                <li><a id="iniciativasFases" href="#tab_iniciativasFases" data-toggle="tab" onclick="iniciativasEstrategicas.GetiniciativasFases()">Iniciativas Fases</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a aria-expanded="true" id="iniciativasTiempos" href="#tab_iniciativasTiempos" data-toggle="tab" onclick="iniciativasEstrategicas.GetVistaEjecucionPendientes('Iniciativas')">Vista Ejecución Pendientes</a></li>
                <li><a id="vistaActividades" href="#tab_vistaActividades" data-toggle="tab" onclick="iniciativasEstrategicas.GetVistaActividades('A tiempo')">Vista Actividades</a></li>
                <li><a id="presupuestos" href="#tab_presupuestos" data-toggle="tab" onclick="iniciativasEstrategicas.GetPresupuestosPorcentaje('Valores')">Presupuestos</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content pestanasDashboardContent">
                <div class="tab-pane iniciativasPorcentaje fade" id="tab_iniciativasPorcentaje"><br><br><div class="table-responsive"><table class="table"><thead><tr><th>Iniciativas</th><th>Porcentaje</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td><a onclick="iniciativasEstrategicas.GetFasesPorcentaje(this)">Empresa Capa Tech S.A.S y Vinculo S.A.</a></td><td><span style="display: none;" class="donut" data-peity="{ &quot;fill&quot;: [&quot;yellow&quot;, &quot;#eeeeee&quot;],  &quot;innerRadius&quot;: 6, &quot;radius&quot;: 12 }">62.50/100</span><svg width="24" height="24" class="peity"><path fill="yellow" d="M 12 0 A 12 12 0 1 1 3.5147186257614305 20.48528137423857 L 7.757359312880715 16.242640687119284 A 6 6 0 1 0 12 6"></path><path fill="#eeeeee" d="M 3.5147186257614305 20.48528137423857 A 12 12 0 0 1 11.999999999999998 0 L 11.999999999999998 6 A 6 6 0 0 0 7.757359312880715 16.242640687119284"></path></svg><span class="percentage">62.50%</span></td></tr><tr><td><a onclick="iniciativasEstrategicas.GetFasesPorcentaje(this)">Proyecto de Actualización Tecnológica</a></td><td><span style="display: none;" class="donut" data-peity="{ &quot;fill&quot;: [&quot;red&quot;, &quot;#eeeeee&quot;],  &quot;innerRadius&quot;: 6, &quot;radius&quot;: 12 }">20.00/100</span><svg width="24" height="24" class="peity"><path fill="red" d="M 12 0 A 12 12 0 0 1 23.412678195541844 8.29179606750063 L 17.706339097770922 10.145898033750315 A 6 6 0 0 0 12 6"></path><path fill="#eeeeee" d="M 23.412678195541844 8.29179606750063 A 12 12 0 1 1 11.999999999999998 0 L 11.999999999999998 6 A 6 6 0 1 0 17.706339097770922 10.145898033750315"></path></svg><span class="percentage">20.00%</span></td></tr><tr><td><a onclick="iniciativasEstrategicas.GetFasesPorcentaje(this)">Definición de modelos de costeo</a></td><td><span style="display: none;" class="donut" data-peity="{ &quot;fill&quot;: [&quot;red&quot;, &quot;#eeeeee&quot;],  &quot;innerRadius&quot;: 6, &quot;radius&quot;: 12 }">12.50/100</span><svg width="24" height="24" class="peity"><path fill="red" d="M 12 0 A 12 12 0 0 1 20.48528137423857 3.5147186257614305 L 16.242640687119284 7.757359312880715 A 6 6 0 0 0 12 6"></path><path fill="#eeeeee" d="M 20.48528137423857 3.5147186257614305 A 12 12 0 1 1 11.999999999999998 0 L 11.999999999999998 6 A 6 6 0 1 0 16.242640687119284 7.757359312880715"></path></svg><span class="percentage">12.50%</span></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div>
                <div class="tab-pane presupuestos fade" id="tab_iniciativasFases">
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane iniciativasFases fade active in" id="tab_iniciativasTiempos"><br><br><div><div><div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example"><button type="button" id="btnVistaIniciativas" class="btn btn-default active" onclick="iniciativasEstrategicas.GetVistaEjecucionPendientes('Iniciativas')">Iniciativas</button><button type="button" id="btnVistaResponsables" class="btn btn-default" onclick="iniciativasEstrategicas.GetVistaEjecucionPendientes('Responsables')">Responsables</button></div></div><div class="table-responsive divTableVistaEjecucionPendientes"><table class="table table-bordered tableVistaEjecucionPendientes"><thead><tr><th rowspan="2">Iniciativas</th><th colspan="4">En Ejecución</th><th colspan="4">Pendientes</th></tr><tr><th colspan="2">A tiempo</th><th colspan="2">Desfasadas</th><th colspan="2">A tiempo</th><th colspan="2">Atrasadas</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>Empresa Capa Tech S.A.S y Vinculo S.A.</td><td>0.00%</td><td>0</td><td>100.00%</td><td>2</td><td>0.00%</td><td>0</td><td>0.00%</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>Proyecto de Actualización Tecnológica</td><td>50.00%</td><td>1</td><td>50.00%</td><td>1</td><td>0.00%</td><td>0</td><td>100.00%</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>Definición de modelos de costeo</td><td>100.00%</td><td>1</td><td>0.00%</td><td>0</td><td>0.00%</td><td>0</td><td>100.00%</td><td>1</td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div>
                <div class="tab-pane iniciativasTiempos fade" id="tab_vistaActividades">
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane vistaActividades fade" id="tab_presupuestos">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane iniciativas fade" id="tab_iniciativas">
            <div id="iniciativasContainer" class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Iniciativas</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div>
                        <form novalidate="novalidate" id="frmAddIniciativa">

                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-group" id="iniciativasList">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/*Fix for bootstrap responsive table*/ 
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  fieldset { display: table-cell; }
}

body {
    padding: 3px;
    overflow: auto !important;
}

/*.table {
    text-align: center;

}*/


.table td,
.table th
{
    text-align:left;
}

#right,
.table td + td,
.table th + th
{
    text-align:center;
}

.table>thead>tr>th {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
}


.tableVistaIniciativasFases td {
    min-width: 100px;
}

.navbar-brand
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}

a:link{cursor:pointer !important;}
a:active{cursor:pointer !important;}
a:visited{cursor:pointer !important;}
a:hover{cursor:pointer !important;}

input {
    -moz-min-width: 10%;
    -ms-min-width: 10%;
    -o-min-width: 10%;
    -webkit-min-width: 10%;
    min-width: 10%;
}

.actions, .panel-heading-iniciativa {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
}

.actionsIniciativas {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-items: center;
}

.actions > a {
    margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
}

#alertIniciativasContainer {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 3px 0 0;
}

.has-error {
    color: #a94442;
}

.deleteButton {
    color: red;
}

.loadImage {
    margin-left: 45%;
}

.divTableVistaActividades, .divTableVistaEjecucionPendientes, .divTablePresupuestos {
    margin-top: 25px;
}

#breadCrumbContainer {
    color: #777777;
    font-size: 19px;
    margin-left: 9px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

    #breadCrumbContainer > span:last-child {
        font-weight: bold;
    }

#editObjetivo, #editIniciativa {
    color: blue;
}

#editIniciativaTemplate {
    margin: 5px;
}

#deleteObjetivo, #cancelUpdateObjetivo, #deleteIniciativa, #cancelUpdateIniciativa {
    color: red;
}

#frmEditObjetivo {
    width: 100%;
}

#inputPatrocinador, #inputPatrocinadorS {
    width: 100%;
}

.idIniciativaValue, #idObjetivoValue, #objetivoValue, #index {
    display: none;
}

#divPatrocinador, #divPatrocinadorS, #divLider, #divLiderS {
    height: 68px !important;
}

#tab_dashboard {
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 0 8px 0 8px;
}

#updateObjetivo, #updateIniciativa {
    color: green;
}

#flexContainer {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

#divPestanasObjetivos {
    display: none;
    flex: 72%;
    order: 2;
}

#patrocinadorPicker, #patrocinadorSPicker {
    margin-right: 3%;
}


#objetivosContainer {
    order: 1;
    -moz-min-width: 168px;
    -ms-min-width: 168px;
    -o-min-width: 168px;
    -webkit-min-width: 168px;
    min-width: 168px;
    flex:100%;
}

#tab_iniciativasFases {
    overflow-x: auto;
}

#txtInput {
    width: 80%;
}

.divIniciativa {
    flex: 1 100%;
    order: 1;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.divButtons {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 17px;
}

#addIniciativa {
    flex: 1 3%;
    order: 4;
    margin: 0 0 10px 3%;
}

#updateIniciativa, #cancelUpdateIniciativa {
    flex: 1 3%;
    order: 4;
    margin: 0 0 10px 3%;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.panel-body {
    padding: 10px 4px !important;
}

.peoplepickerContainer {
    flex: 1 40%;
    order: 3;
}

.cam-peoplepicker-userlookup {
    height: 68px !important;
}

.objetivoItemButtons a, .iniciativaItemButtons a {
    margin: 7px;
}

.objetivoItemButtons {
    flex: 1 20%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}



.objetivoItemContainer {
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    cursor: pointer;
}

    .objetivoItemContainer:hover {
        background-color: #EEE;
    }

.objetivoItem {
    flex: 2 70%;
    margin: 0;
}

.panel-title-flex {
    flex: 2 0;
}

.percentage {
    margin-left: 9px;
    vertical-align: inherit;
}

.totalValoresPresupuesto {
    padding-top: 7px;
}
```